# Почему def запускается без нажатия на кнопку?

Tags: python, классы, tkinter

Вот быстренько написал микропрограммку с такой проблемой:

```py
from tkinter import *


class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('100x50')
        self.button = Button(text='Go', command=App.start(self))
        self.button.pack()

    def start(self):
        print('Тест')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()
```

Слово "Тест" пишется при запуске программы, а не при нажатии кнопки.
Почему так происходит и как это исправить?

Comment: потому что `App.start(self)` вызывается при назначении кнопки, надо `command=App.start`

Comment: @splash58. Но если я так пишу то выдаётся ошибка : `TypeError: App.start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`, что нужно сделать чтобы и self передать и запускать функцию при нажатии на кнопку?

Comment: `..., command=self.start`

Comment: сделать start статическим методом, потому что button ничего не передает; использовать `lambda : <тут нужный вызов>`

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA. Спасибо! Очень сильно помогли.

Comment: @splash58. Решение от Романа гораздо легче